# Value of textbar is not shown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on modal box pop up for HTML form generation using row id. But i don't why some error is there for not displaying text in `textbar`.

1) My `textbar` is not showing the value in HTML page, which it is getting from JSON button but i can see it in my inspect element.

2) `select option` in HTML not getting pre-selected based on value of JSON.

You can see at below

[image]

Part of `modal.js` file which is adding form element using ajax function.

```
form.append('<div class="row"><div class="col span-1-of-3"><label>Description: </label></div><div class="col span-2-of-3"><textarea type="text" name="leaddescription" value="'+value['LeadDescription']+'"></textarea></div></div>')

form.append('<div class="row"><div class="col span-1-of-3"><label>Admin Notes: </label></div><div class="col span-2-of-3"><textarea type="text" name="adminnotes" value="'+value['AdminNotes']+'"></textarea></div></div>')

form.append('<div class="row"><div class="col span-1-of-3"><label>Owner Notes: </label></div><div class="col span-2-of-3"><textarea type="text" name="ownernotes" value="'+value['OwnerNotes']+'" ></textarea></div></div>')

form.append('<div class="row"><div class="col span-1-of-3"><label>Lead Status: </label></div><div class="col span-2-of-3"><div class="col span-1-of-3"><select name="leadstatus" id="leadstatus" value="'+value['LeadStatus']+'"><option>Select</option><option value="Active">Active</option><option value="Paused">Paused</option><option value="Expired">Expired</option><option value="Unsubscribed">Unsubscribed</option></select></div></div></div>')

$("leadstatus select").val(value['LeadStatus']);

form.append('<div class="row"><div class="col span-1-of-3"></div><div class="col span-2-of-3"><input type="submit" name="update_lead_submit" value="Update"></div></div>')
```

Complete `modal.js` file

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('[name="leadidclick"]').click(function(e){

      e.preventDefault();
      // var leadid = $('[name="leadidclick"]').val();

      var leadid = $(this).val();

      alert("You clicked Leadid: " + leadid);

       $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: './server/modal.php',
        data: {

          'leadid': leadid

        },        
        success: function(data){

          var result = $.parseJSON(data);
          console.log(result);

          // console.log(result.length)
          //Modal Box to POP UP HERE

          $('#formapp').empty(); // first empty division content 

          var form=''; //declare var

          $.each(result, function(key, value) {

                    form = $("<form action='' method='POST'></form>").attr("id", value['Lead_Id']);                                               

                    form.append('<div class="row"><div class="col span-1-of-3"><label>Lead Id: </label></div><div class="col span-2-of-3"><input type="text" name="leadid" value="'+value['Lead_Id']+'"></div>');

                    form.append('<div class="row"><div class="col span-1-of-3"><label>Name: </label></div><div class="col span-2-of-3"><div class="row"><div class="col span-1-of-2"><input type="text" name="first_name" value="'+value['FirstName']+'"></div><div class="col span-1-of-2"><input type="text" name="last_name" value="'+value['LastName']+'"></div></div></div></div>')

                    form.append('<div class="row"><div class="col span-1-of-3"><label>Company: </label></div><div class="col span-2-of-3"><input type="text" name="company_name" value="'+value['Company']+'"></div>');

                    form.append('<div class="row"><div class="col span-1-of-3"><label>Website: </label></div><div class="col span-2-of-3"><input type="text" name="website_name" value="'+value['Website']+'"></div></div>')

                    form.append('<div class="row"><div class="col span-1-of-3"><label>Designation: </label></div><div class="col span-2-of-3"><input type="text" name="designation_name" value="'+value['Designation']+'"></div></div>')

                    form.append('<div class="row"><div class="col span-1-of-3"><label>Linkedin: </label></div><div class="col span-2-of-3"><input type="text" name="linkedin_name" value="'+value['Linkedin']+'"></div></div>')

                    form.append('<div class="row"><div class="col span-1-of-3"><label>Email: </label></div><div class="col span-2-of-3"><input type="email" name="email_name" value="'+value['Email']+'" ></div></div>')

                    form.append('<div class="row"><div class="col span-1-of-3"><label>Phone: </label></div><div class="col span-2-of-3"><input type="text" name="phone" value="'+value['Phone']+'"></div></div>')

                    form.append('<div class="row"><div class="col span-1-of-3"><label>State: </label></div><div class="col span-2-of-3"><input type="text" name="state" value="'+value['State']+'"></div></div>')

                    form.append('<div class="row"><div class="col span-1-of-3"><label>Country: </label></div><div class="col span-2-of-3"><input type="text" name="country" value="'+value['Country']+'"></div></div>')

                    form.append('<div class="row"><div class="col span-1-of-3"><label>Tech Area: </label></div><div class="col span-2-of-3"><input type="text" name="techarea" value="'+value['TechArea']+'"></div></div>')

                    form.append('<div class="row"><div class="col span-1-of-3"><label>Firm Type: </label></div><div class="col span-2-of-3"><input type="text" name="firmtype" value="'+value['FirmType']+'"></div></div>')

                    form.append('<div class="row"><div class="col span-1-of-3"><label>Firm Size: </label></div><div class="col span-2-of-3"><input type="text" name="firmsize" value="'+value['FirmSize']+'"></div></div>')

                    form.append('<div class="row"><div class="col span-1-of-3"><label>Last Contact Date: </label></div><div class="col span-2-of-3"><input type="date" name="lastcontactdate" value="'+value['LastContactDate']+'"></div></div>')

                    form.append('<div class="row"><div class="col span-1-of-3"><label>Next Contact Date: </label></div><div class="col span-2-of-3"><input type="date" name="nextcontactdate" value="'+value['NextContactDate']+'"></div></div>')

                    form.append('<div class="row"><div class="col span-1-of-3"><label>Set Reminder Date: </label></div><div class="col span-2-of-3"><input type="date" name="setreminderdate" value="'+value['SetReminder']+'"></div></div>')

                    form.append('<div class="row"><div class="col span-1-of-3"><label>Description: </label></div><div class="col span-2-of-3"><textarea type="text" name="leaddescription" value="'+value['LeadDescription']+'"></textarea></div></div>')

                    form.append('<div class="row"><div class="col span-1-of-3"><label>Admin Notes: </label></div><div class="col span-2-of-3"><textarea type="text" name="adminnotes" value="'+value['AdminNotes']+'"></textarea></div></div>')

                    form.append('<div class="row"><div class="col span-1-of-3"><label>Owner Notes: </label></div><div class="col span-2-of-3"><textarea type="text" name="ownernotes" value="'+value['OwnerNotes']+'" ></textarea></div></div>')

                    form.append('<div class="row"><div class="col span-1-of-3"><label>Lead Status: </label></div><div class="col span-2-of-3"><div class="col span-1-of-3"><select name="leadstatus" id="leadstatus" value="'+value['LeadStatus']+'"><option>Select</option><option value="Active">Active</option><option value="Paused">Paused</option><option value="Expired">Expired</option><option value="Unsubscribed">Unsubscribed</option></select></div></div></div>')

                    $("leadstatus select").val(value['LeadStatus']);

                    form.append('<div class="row"><div class="col span-1-of-3"></div><div class="col span-2-of-3"><input type="submit" name="update_lead_submit" value="Update"></div></div>')

                    // form.append()

                    // form.append('<input type="button" value="button">');                    

          });


          $( "#formapp" ).html( form );

          $('#myModal').show();         


        }

      });

    });

});
```

File `dashboard.html` where ajax send html FORM code

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

                                      <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>



        <div id="formapp">
        </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add html code instead of images. Someone would like to represent your issue.

Comment: HTML is generated by this AJAX function using  JSON of result it get from server PHP pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first append the element and then set values for all those appended elements from jQuery to update the DOM tree and set the values for those elements:

```js
var form = $('form');
var value = {
  "LeadDescription": "LeadDescription",
  "AdminNotes": "AdminNotes",
  "OwnerNotes": "OwnerNotes",
  "LeadStatus": "Active"
}
form.append('<div class="row"><div class="col span-1-of-3"><label>Description: </label></div><div class="col span-2-of-3"><textarea type="text" name="leaddescription"></textarea></div></div>');

form.append('<div class="row"><div class="col span-1-of-3"><label>Admin Notes: </label></div><div class="col span-2-of-3"><textarea type="text" name="adminnotes"></textarea></div></div>');

form.append('<div class="row"><div class="col span-1-of-3"><label>Owner Notes: </label></div><div class="col span-2-of-3"><textarea type="text" name="ownernotes"></textarea></div></div>');

form.append('<div class="row"><div class="col span-1-of-3"><label>Lead Status: </label></div><div class="col span-2-of-3"><div class="col span-1-of-3"><select name="leadstatus" id="leadstatus" value="' + value['LeadStatus'] + '"><option>Select</option><option value="Active">Active</option><option value="Paused">Paused</option><option value="Expired">Expired</option><option value="Unsubscribed">Unsubscribed</option></select></div></div></div>');

form.append('<div class="row"><div class="col span-1-of-3"></div><div class="col span-2-of-3"><input type="submit" name="update_lead_submit" value="Update"></div></div>');

// set values now
$('[name="leaddescription"]').val(value['LeadDescription']);
$('[name="ownernotes"]').val(value['OwnerNotes']);
$('[name="adminnotes"]').val(value['AdminNotes']);
$("#leadstatus").val(value['LeadStatus']);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form></form>
```

If you want to do the other way then you can use `<textarea>VALUE</textarea>`

```js
var form = $('form');
var value = {
  "LeadDescription": "LeadDescription",
  "AdminNotes": "AdminNotes",
  "OwnerNotes": "OwnerNotes",
  "LeadStatus": "Active"
}
form.append('<div class="row"><div class="col span-1-of-3"><label>Description: </label></div><div class="col span-2-of-3"><textarea type="text" name="leaddescription">' + value['LeadDescription'] + '</textarea></div></div>');

form.append('<div class="row"><div class="col span-1-of-3"><label>Admin Notes: </label></div><div class="col span-2-of-3"><textarea type="text" name="adminnotes">' + value['AdminNotes'] + '</textarea></div></div>');

form.append('<div class="row"><div class="col span-1-of-3"><label>Owner Notes: </label></div><div class="col span-2-of-3"><textarea type="text" name="ownernotes">' + value['OwnerNotes'] + '</textarea></div></div>');

form.append('<div class="row"><div class="col span-1-of-3"><label>Lead Status: </label></div><div class="col span-2-of-3"><div class="col span-1-of-3"><select name="leadstatus" id="leadstatus" value="' + value['LeadStatus'] + '"><option>Select</option><option value="Active">Active</option><option value="Paused">Paused</option><option value="Expired">Expired</option><option value="Unsubscribed">Unsubscribed</option></select></div></div></div>');

$("#leadstatus").val(value['LeadStatus']);

form.append('<div class="row"><div class="col span-1-of-3"></div><div class="col span-2-of-3"><input type="submit" name="update_lead_submit" value="Update"></div></div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form></form>
```

Comment: that means i used unnecessarily this  `form.append('')`

Comment: what about select option?

Comment: @RINKS it is not `unnecessarily`. It is just a good practice to separate the appending of dynamic added elements and initialization of their values. Also select option would work the way you have done but you need use the right selector `$("#leadstatus")`. Also, you need to use `<textarea>value['adminNotes']</textarea>`

Comment: I am using this `$("leadstatus select").val(value['LeadStatus']);`

Comment: Your selector is incorrect `$("leadstatus select")`. You do not have any element with `<leadstatus>` it is an id so you need to use ``$("#leadstatus")`. I have also updated the answer, check it.

Comment: @RINKS I haven't deleted anything. Check the answer. There are two code snippets to make you more clear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206126/discussion-between-ankit-agarwal-and-rinks).

Comment: can this happening because i am using more than one JQuery links

Answer (score 1):

> If you want to show description inside textarea then you have to simply print you value inside textarea.

`<textarea> this is textarea.<textarea/>`

the `<textarea><textarea/>` tag only shows the value when we define the value inside the tag

```
form.append('<div class="row"><div class="col span-1-of-3"><label>Description: </label></div><div class="col span-2-of-3"><textarea type="text" name="leaddescription"> value['LeadDescription'] </textarea></div></div>');

form.append('<div class="row"><div class="col span-1-of-3"><label>Admin Notes: </label></div><div class="col span-2-of-3"><textarea type="text" name="adminnotes"> value['AdminNotes'] </textarea></div></div>');
```

Comment: what about select option?

Comment: That thing will not work for `value="something"` inside `<textarea>` tag

Answer (score 1):

It is better if you can insert your HTML codes in a single text line in PHP file and append at once.

Instead of use `form.append` multiple times, create a variable and add HTML lines to it, then append it at once.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post some code samples within your answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.